# Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider || Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

The android build is crashing on launch after integrating crashlytics. issue is also posted on github at here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30828. When I run the application on device it start Initializing Crashlytics and the initialization successful but the app is crashed with this error.

**Error**

```
2021-02-02 12:38:54.894 24528-24528/com.ryseup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ryseup, PID: 24528
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ryseup-UPmGRFNEOmi2dcvGtmIabQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ryseup-UPmGRFNEOmi2dcvGtmIabQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.ryseup-UPmGRFNEOmi2dcvGtmIabQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6721)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ryseup-UPmGRFNEOmi2dcvGtmIabQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ryseup-UPmGRFNEOmi2dcvGtmIabQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.ryseup-UPmGRFNEOmi2dcvGtmIabQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6721) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

**react-native info**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.0.1
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    Memory: 26.82 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.12.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.2, DriverKit 20.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.2, watchOS 7.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 26, 28, 29, 30
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.2
      System Images: android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
    Xcode: 12.2/12B45b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_275 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for inconvience!
It is fixed for now I have used Facebook login in the past but now it is removed from react-native code and package.json but the integration not removed from the android side.

I removed these lines

```
---      <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
---      <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider249341956089060 android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
---          android:exported="true" />
```

[image]

Comment: manifest also causes app crashes !